# Is it possible to scan the LAN with ajax to find a specific server?

Tags: javascript, ajax, networking, lan

Okay, so I am deploying hardware that a user could stick on their LAN. I plan on making AJAX calls to the LAN hardware, but I don't want to have a hard-coded IP address for the device, as I don't want to make the user fiddle with their DHCP server or anything. So, is it possible to have AJAX/JavaScript scan the LAN until it finds the my hardware on the network?

(I'd rather not have AJAX go through every possible LAN IP, but I think that is the only way to do it)

Comment: i would have the LAN device report it's IP to a website that code making the ajax calls can fetch from. or have the user enter it in.

Comment: the LAN might not necessarily have internet access though.

Comment: since JS alone cannot determine the local IP, you'll need internet for setup or a textbox to enter the IP manually. keep in mind that if it's using dhcp, the IP can change at any time as far as JS is concerned because JS can't see the lease info either...

Comment: I'm not trying to determine the user's local IP, I'm trying to scan their network to find a server (the correct server will return a specific result). So, I feel like testing every LAN IP is the only way, but I don't feel like it's efficient.

Comment: i was implying that if you knew even the local IP, you'de only have to scan 250 addresses... i guess you can assume 192.168 for consumers, but that still leaves 250*250 machines to ping...

Comment: Yeah, but then I don't even know what to do if the user's network is on IPv6 or a non-standard IP range.

Comment: that text box is looking better and better... good luck on your box.

Comment: Javascript in browser engine has high isolation from externals on the same computer. You don't want do some ajax code delete your documents? ;)  Indirect scan MAC/IP I guess is impossible. AJAX cap present data i.e. from LAN (www) server which can perform scanning